# Bulk change runningUserId on dashboards

Tags: query, dashboard, update

Is there any way i can change the running user on several dashboards in bulk via back-end?

I did not see dashboard to be listed as updateable objects. But, wanted to check with geniuses here if there are any other ways i can do this.

Comment: probably you can refer this ans: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BSWVIA4

Comment: Ok Thanks Santanu! I did check that earlier. But, was wondering if there is any way to do updates on the dashboard object directly.